# laravel authentication redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I'm new to Laravel and have just added the Authentication package to an existing project.

Upon logging in, I want to be redirected to /Result a page that that I know works using a controller. If I type the URL /Result the page loads correctly but when I login I am being redirected to index each time rather than /Result

**Routes**

```
  Route::get('/result','ResultsController@getResults')->name('result');
  Auth::routes();
  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('/');
```

**Home Controller**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('result');
    }
}
```

**Results Controller**

```
class ResultsController extends Controller
{
    public function getResults( )
    {
        $results = Result::all();
        return view('/result', ['results' => $results]);
    } 
}
```

**Login Controller**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'result';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

/**
 * @return 
 */
public function authenticated()
{
return redirect()->route('result');
}
}
```

So far I can load index and be redirected to login, when I login I want to be redirected to /Result but instead I recieve an Undefined variable: results.

I have jumped to /Results by manipulating the URL and the page /Results does work.

Any help would be much appreciated, just le me know if you need any additional code examples from any other files.

thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change the route name format use only result.

```
Route::get('/result','ResultsController@getResults')->name('result')
```

For redirect any route you can use LoginController authenticate method.
\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

Add this method to that controller:

```
/**
 * @return 
 */
public function authenticated()
{
    return redirect()->route('result');
}
```

Comment: thanks though I am still getting the same issue; I've updated the original post

Comment: Where is your view file stored? In views directories?

Comment: Try this in you getResults method return view('result', compact('results'));

Comment: i think your original response was the correct solution as it is now working but I had to clear my cache to see the change, thanks Nayeem, I struggled a bit with this one